# get multi selection value from lookup field using java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, multi-select

I nee d get mutiple value from a lookup field and i need to validate it,if i get more than one value i need to give a message and if get one value i need to give another message.i have try something but it not work.

```js
function getbankdetails()
{     
  debugger;
  var arr = $('#R3413775').val();
  
  if(arr[0]!="" && arr[1] !="")
  {
    alert("first"+arr[0]+" "+arr[1]);
  }
  else
  { 
    alert("sasa");
  }  
  
}
```

Comment: why are you cheching arr[0] 2 times in if condition

Comment: actually it is mistake but it is not real problem,i change it and check again it not work if i use arr[0] and arr[1]

Comment: can u share your output? I have given an answer if you share your exact output and expected output it will be clear

Comment: @saketh according to the above code when i select one value alert show " first value undefined" if i select two values alert show in twice first time show " first value undefine" and second time show "first value value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work (Javascript)

```
function getbankdetails()
{     
  debugger;
  var arr = Array.from(document.getElementById("R3413775").selectedOptions).map((ele) => ele.value)      
  if(arr[0] && arr[1] && arr.length == 2)
  {
     alert("first"+arr[0]+" "+arr[1]);
  }
  else
  { 
     alert("sasa");
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the elements as the array and either console log the "sasa" string or the list of selected items as a string (by concatenating the array with commas.

```js
$('#R3413775').change(function(){
  getbankdetails();
})

function getbankdetails() {     
  var arr = $('#R3413775').val();
  arr.length == 1 
   ? console.log("sasa")
   : console.log(arr.join(', '))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="R3413775" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" >Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```